# Generating custom ID for my application

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to generate a custom ID for one of the feature in my application. Here is the procedure to do that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextVendorInvoiceNo]
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @StartingVendorInvoiceNo    int = 0

    Select @StartingVendorInvoiceNo = MAX(StartingVendorInvoiceNo) + 1
        From SystemSettings WITH (TABLOCK)

    Update SystemSettings
            Set StartingVendorInvoiceNo = @StartingVendorInvoiceNo  


    Select @StartingVendorInvoiceNo 

END
```

Would there be any issue if multiple users end up calling this procedure. Obviously I don't want multiple users to have the same ID. I am using TABLOCK but not sure if this is the right way or anything else too is required.

Comment: Does the startingvendorinvoiceno ever change? If not, why can't you have an identity column instead?

Comment: Because this is a simpler version on ints. I plan to have varchar later on for generation of invoice and as I suggested in the question Identity is not possible.

Comment: Why isn't identity possible? If all you're doing is getting the previous maximum value and adding one, then you're doing exactly what an identity does in a less efficient manner.

Comment: @ZLK: Did you care to read my comment? I said I plan to do it on varchar so invoice no could then be ZXCVA - all unique. I hope you understand it isn't possible in Identity. I would appreciate if you just answer my queries instead of suggesting a different way which isn't possible in my case.

Comment: Then realisitically speaking, what you're doing is far more complex than it needs to be (because you could add "ZXCVA" in whatever application you need to display "ZXCVA" in, but have the ACTUAL field be an integer). If your field is going to be varchar then it's not as simple as max+1, you have to split the values in the column, find the integer, then add 1 to it, then insert it... But really, you SHOULD just keep it as an int.

Comment: @ZLK: I think you just don't want to read my comment and keep proposing a different solution which isn't a solution at all. Kindly read "I said I plan to do it on **varchar** so invoice no could then be ZXCVA - all unique" I am just looking for whether my TABLOCK keyword is proper or not or could it cause any issue if multiple users call at the same time.. Complex or not I can handle it later. I just need whether locking is implemented properly or not.  if you do not know the solution please stop don't bother please.

Comment: Yeah, literally nothing in your opening post says "I want to make all my IDs varchar at some point, so I just pasted some code that increments a number for no reason". Regardless, notice how this is a comment and not an answer? That's because I'm _commenting_ on how poor your idea is, and suggesting a _better_ one.

Comment: Opening post doesn't say but your extended comment on still proposing Identity came after I said I would use varchar at some point. So your extended comments makes no sense. In any case please refer Vladimir solution as it is the perfect way and exactly what I am looking for. Poor is your comment and not the idea.

Comment: Yes, you said "I plan to use varchar" which doesn't imply "I plan to do something that doesn't resemble the sample code I gave at all..." I assumed you meant "I plan to add a string to an invoice number like ZXCVA1010101, ZXCVA1010102", but regardless, your idea is a bad one.

Comment: May god give you some wits is all I could say :) You still didn't understand. Invoice number could be anything ZXVAV, TYAAAA, JHKJKJ a unique varchar number and not just limiting to ints. You still don't quiet seem to understand what I want to do. You keep telling the idea is bad one but you still don't know what the solution should be and haven't posted a better one. In future please try to solve the OP's question rather than forcing him to accept his question is not valid at all. Regardless please read Vladimir's solution hopefully you get to learn a thing or two. Thanks!

Comment: No, I understand perfectly what you're trying to do now. I'm saying you're not very smart for doing that, and saying "I plan to use VARCHAR" doesn't imply what you're saying it implied, so you're doubly stupid for pretending people should have guessed what you meant before you made it explicit. It IS a bad idea. The solution you just marked as an answer just doesn't do anything if there's a lock. Realistically, what you should be doing is waiting for the lock to end then inserting. OR, better yet, calculating the unique ID after insert (e.g. based on an identity) so that locks don't matter.

Comment: And yet still no answer except your BAD BAD thing:) That isn't very smart either is it? That kind of attitude is not going to get you far. Anyways good luck. The solution is perfect and works fine. Just read on sp_getapplock there is timeout mentioned: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

Comment: :roll: you're truly hopeless, and I wish you the best with your awful ideas.

Comment: You're a bigger one :)

Comment: @ZLK, to be fair, `sp_getapplock` **is** waiting for the given period (60 seconds in my code) for the lock to be released. It is just a simple way to serialise access to a resource (a mutex, if you wish). Simple, compared to using query hints.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: I completely understand but he is just a pathetic hopeless troll who simply doesn't understand the question / other people's answer neither wants to answer but wants to keep mumbling the question is wrong the idea is wrong and blah blah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 has [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) feature, which is definitely safe for multi-user environment. It is based on an integer type, though.

If you have a complex procedure that generates a "next" ID and you want to make sure that only one instance of the procedure runs at any moment (at the expense of throughput), I'd use [`sp_getapplock'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx). It is easy to use and understand and you don't need to worry about placing correct query hints.

Your procedure would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextVendorInvoiceNo]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @VarLockResult int;
        EXEC @VarLockResult = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = 'GetNextVendorInvoiceNo_app_lock',
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
            @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
            @LockTimeout = 60000,
            @DbPrincipal = 'public';

        Declare @StartingVendorInvoiceNo int = 0;

        IF @VarLockResult >= 0
        BEGIN
            -- Acquired the lock, generate the "next" ID
            Select @StartingVendorInvoiceNo = MAX(StartingVendorInvoiceNo) + 1
            From SystemSettings;

            Update SystemSettings
            Set StartingVendorInvoiceNo = @StartingVendorInvoiceNo;

        END ELSE BEGIN
            -- TODO: handle the case when it takes too long to acquire the lock,
            -- i.e. return some error code
            -- For example, return 0
            SET @StartingVendorInvoiceNo = 0;
        END;

        Select @StartingVendorInvoiceNo;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        -- TODO: handle the error
    END CATCH;

END
```

---

Simple `TABLOCK` as you wrote is definitely not enough. You need to wrap everything into transaction. Then make sure that lock is held till the end of the transaction, see `HOLDLOCK`. Then make sure that the lock you are getting is the correct one. You may need `TABLOCKX`. So, overall you need a pretty good understanding of all these hints and how locking works. It is definitely possible to achieve the same effect with these hints. But, if the logic in the procedure is more complicated than your simplified example it can easily get pretty ugly.

To my mind, `sp_getapplock` is easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: Super work. Thank you so much! Just so I understand my TABLOCK will not work?

Comment: @TimLiberty, See expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!